Sharpness of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem
Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Lebesgue measure zero set. Is it possible to find a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that (where $|.|$ is the absolute value)
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|dx<\infty
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
A = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \limsup_{r\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{r^n}\int_{|y-x|<r } |f(y)-f(x)|dy >0\right\}
\end{align*}

The answer is yes, just put $f\equiv 1$ on $A$ and $f\equiv 0$ on $A^c$. Since $A$ has measure zero, the absolute value inside the integral is $0$ a.e. if $x\in A^c$, and $1$ a.e. if $x\in A$.
However, given a null set $B$, we might not be able to find a non-negative integrable $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $B=B_f$, where
$$
B_f=\left\{\limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{1}{r}\int_{|y-x|<r}f(y)\,dy=+\infty \right\}.
$$
(As the links in the other answer show, we can always find an $f$ such that $B\subset B_f$, even with if we replace $\limsup$ by $\liminf$.) For each $m,k\in\mathbb{N}$,  the set
$$
E_{m,k}=\left\{ x:\exists q<\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{q}\int_{|y-x|\leq q}|f(y)|\,dy>k\right\}
$$
is open. Since $B_f=\cup_{k}\cap_{m}E_{m,k},$ it is always a Borel set, and not every null set is Borel.

It is not clear to me how the characteristic function of $A$ would suffice as an example

The answer is yes, see exercise 25 in chapter 3 of Stein-Shakarchi's book on real analysis and this question.

This answers a slightly different question though, as it constructs $f$ such that $A$ is contained in the set on the RHS, not necessarily equal.

@Kostya_I right, I agree with your comment and your answer, +1.
